# Find all asymptotes of given curve

Tags: asymptotics, algebraic-curves

> $y^2(a+x) = x^2(a-x)$
>
> origin i found will be a node
>
> i'm trying to find asymptotes by equating highest degree term to $0$
>
> Please help.

Comment: What exactly are $x$, $y$ and $a$? What is an *asymptote*?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jusycz7ky4

Answer (score 0):

write $y(x)=mx+b$ and then rearrange equation in the form $\sum_0^n a_nx^n=0$, where n is the highest degree term you get once you rearrange equation. Now you set $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$ to $0$ and for each pair {m,b} found you get an asymptote. in your case if i didn't make any mistakes you should find only one asymptote at $x=-a$

Comment: Yeah, that's the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider 
$y^2(a+x) = x^2(b-x)
$,
with
$a, b \ne 0$.

Since
$(0, 0)$
is a point on
this curve,
suppose
$y'(0) = c$.

Note that
this is more general.

Then,
for small $x$ and $y$,
$y \approx cx$.

Then
$(cx)^2(a+x) \approx x^2(b-x)
$
or
$c^2(a+x) \approx b-x
$
or,
since
$x$ is small,
$c^2a \approx b$
or
$c^2 \approx b/a$.

Therefore
$c = \pm \sqrt{b/a}$
so there are
two asymptotes
at the origin
with slopes
$\pm \sqrt{b/a}
$.

In your case,
since
$a=b$,
the slopes are
$\pm 1$.